# What is the difference of sourcing a video from local folder rather than online url in html?

Tags: javascript, html, css

As my questions states above, is there a significant difference between using an mp4 file from my folder rather than grabbing the url from online performance wise? My code below is using an online url source to grab the two videos. When you scroll past a certain point on the page the background video will change and it works as I want it to as of now. But when I replace that source with a local mp4 video in my folder, the video will play in the bakcground but every time the user scroll it just restarts rather than continue playing until the if condition is met for it to switch. I am not sure why the logic in the javascript functioned well with the url source but not with local mp4 video source, is there something I am missing? or a better way to make this work?

Thank you!

```js
 var video = document.getElementById('video-background');
  var source = document.createElement('source');
  

  window.onscroll = function(){
  console.log(document.body.scrollTop);
  console.log(document.documentElement.scrollTop);
     if (document.documentElement.scrollTop > 200) {   
     if(video.src !== 'https://storage.googleapis.com/coverr-main/mp4/The-Slow-Dock.mp4'){
      video.src='https://storage.googleapis.com/coverr-main/mp4/The-Slow-Dock.mp4';
      }
      
          } 
      else{
       if(video.src !== 'https://storage.googleapis.com/coverr-main/mp4/Night-Traffic.mp4')
        video.src='https://storage.googleapis.com/coverr-main/mp4/Night-Traffic.mp4';
        
       }



      
        };
```

```css
.section {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  overflow: hidden;
}
body{
  height: 500px;
}

.video-container {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<body>

    <div class="section">

        <h1>1</h1>

        <div class="video-container">
            
            <video autoplay loop id="video-background" muted >
              <source type="video/mp4" src="https://storage.googleapis.com/coverr-main/mp4/Night-Traffic.mp4">
            </video>
        </div>
           
 
  </div>     
</body>
```

Comment: Are you sure you copied correctly the **new** url in the `if` blocks too? Did you use a relative url (without `http://localhost`)? Accessing the `.src` attribute should return the full-path (though it's risky to count on that). In your position, I'd keep track of which video is currently loaded in a js variable rather than relying on this property. Can you show that version of the code too?

Comment: yeah so the rather than the https url, I changed that to Edwin.mp4 which is the video i want to use instead located in the same file as the code so I put it as video.src='Edwin.mp4' in my if blocks and it plays in the background just doesn't follow the code logic. I will try .src attribute.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's a bit of long shot, but given your description of the problem, I can't see a thousands possibilities.

So to me it sounds like you are testing the wrong urls in your `if()` blocks, probably because you used a relative url there. At getting the `.src` property will return the full-path url:

```js
const url = document.getElementById( 'vid' ).src;
console.log( url );
if( url !== "../relative.mp4" ) {
  console.log( "that's a problem" );
}
```

```html
<video id="vid" src="../relative.mp4"></video>
```

To workaround that, the easy solution is to keep the current url in a js variable:

```js
var video = document.getElementById('video-background');
var source = document.createElement('source');
var urls = [
  "https://storage.googleapis.com/coverr-main/mp4/The-Slow-Dock.mp4",
  "https://storage.googleapis.com/coverr-main/mp4/Night-Traffic.mp4"
];
var currentURL = 0;

window.onscroll = function() {
  if (document.documentElement.scrollTop > 200) {
    if (currentURL !== 0) {
      currentURL = 0;
      video.src = urls[currentURL];
    }
  } else {
    if (currentURL !== 1) {
      currentURL = 1;
      video.src = urls[currentURL];
    }
  }
}
```

```css
.section {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  overflow: hidden;
}

body {
  height: 500px;
}

.video-container {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="section">
  <h1>1</h1>
  <div class="video-container">
    <video autoplay loop id="video-background" muted>
      <source type="video/mp4" src="https://storage.googleapis.com/coverr-main/mp4/Night-Traffic.mp4">
    </video>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: ok so in the javascript grab the video with .src then use it that way? I will try it out. but yes I was trying to grab the video.mp4 in my folder and it is located in the same file as code for  now so I just called it as src='edwin.mp4' in my if blocks (video name is edwin).

Comment: It's better to use js variables or even an Array of urls like I did rather than grabbing from `.src`.

Comment: Ok so I can't get it to work still. but yes so instead of all the https in my if statements I need them to be checking the videos in my local folder (located in same file). So in my javascript file am I doing it wrong by doing my if statement as... if (video.src1!=="../edwin.mp4") then video.src="../edwin.mp4"?

Comment: Yes you are doing it wrong since `video.src` --> `"http://localhost/edwin.mp4"` and that this string is not the same as `"../edwin.mp4"`.

Comment: Oh ok i see, I need to set it exactly to the correct path as that is what i am comparing it to. Noob question but how would I be able to check if that's the exact path and how did you know that was the exact path? I tried outputing it on console to see but couldn't. So then in the future if I were to use a domain I would assume the exact path would change.

Comment: Look at the snippet in my answer, I store these as strings in an array and then just change the `currentURL` index. No need to know how it's been parsed, I only rely on something I know for sure I have full control over.

Comment: I can see it working for known urls (the ones I got online) but say I have video files on the local folder called vid1.mp4, vid2.mp4 etc. I would have to fill out that array in your answer with the string of the full paths of those local videos insead, so then how would you get those paths? or know what the string value is.

Comment: How would you have known this with your approach of hard-coding it in the `if()` blocks?